# Ошибка: "... cannot be resolved or is not a field"

Tags: java, android

Проблема заключается в следующем участке кода.

```
int restId=R.drawable.im1+i;
```

Текст ошибки:

> im1 cannot be resolved or is not a field

Содержимое класса `R`.

```
public final class R {
    public static final class attr {
    }
    public static final class drawable {
        public static final int hzk12=0x7f020000;
        public static final int ic_action_search=0x7f020001;
        public static final int ic_launcher=0x7f020002;
        public static final int im1=0x7f020003;
```

Подскажите, что не так?

*UPD*

Код для Андроид 4.0.3. Может там какие-то другие способы обращения к значениям в классе `R`?

Comment: не делай это, зачем?

Comment: Такое использование R.id это извращение попахивающее в лучшем случае хаком, а в худшем безграмотностью. Выглядит оч. плохо. Примерно как если к номеру автомашины самостоятельно пририсовать сзади "1" или "0" - как говорится до первого гаишника - в лучшем случае нарветесь на штраф, а в худшем вплоть до уголовки.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Специально проверил. Все компилируется и работает (если конечно понимать, что произойдет).

Скорее всего Вы забыли подключить R файл к данному файлу. Вверху файла должна быть строка вида

```
import org.your.project.name.R;
```

Но у вас там может быть

```
import android.R;
```

В нем то `R.android.drawable` есть, то Вашего im1 там не будет (по понятным причинам).

Но ещё раз замечу, что конструкции вида `int restId=R.drawable.im1+i;`, если дальше по этому id будете получать drawable, может привести к чему угодно. В лучшем случае загрузится либо не то, либо будет исключение. Нужно помнить, что при следующей компиляции компилятор может переставить идентификаторы ресурсов в одному ему понятном порядке.

Comment: KoVadim спасибо за ответ, все заработало. Пока возвращался домой думал о таком способе )